# How do I represent this regular expression in regular grammar?

Tags: formal-grammars

**Question:** Is the regular expression and regular grammar equivalent?
I've look on some examples of regular grammar however I don't think I fully understand how to convert regular expression to its equivalent grammar. So I am also asking for some help or tips to convert regular expression to regular grammar.

***Key**

() -> empty string*

**Regular Expression** :
a* (ba (cf* (g (f + j)* b f*)*  e)* a)*

**Regular Grammar**:

S-> aS| ()

F-> f F| ()

Q-> fQ | jQ | ()

G -> gQB|()

C-> cFGE| ()

E-> eC

M -> baCA|()

A -> aM

LM = {L1 | L1= SM }

Comment: In a regular grammar, every production has at most one non-terminal in its right-hand side, and in all the right-hand sides in the grammar with a non-terminal, the non-terminal is the last symbol in the right-hand side. (That's a right-regular grammar. There are also left-regular grammars, where the non-terminals are always the first symbol. But the two sets of grammars describe the same set of languages, the regular languages.) So, for example, $C\to cFGE$ cannot appear in a regular grammar (more than one non-terminal).

Comment: I didn't know that there were right-regular grammars and left-regular grammars I just figured that in assigning a terminal to a non-terminal the non-terminal must always be placed on the left. Thank you for that insight

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent in the sense that every language that can be represented with a regular expression, can be represented with a regular grammar; and vice versa.

Also, you can convert any regular grammar to a regular expression that generates the same language, and vice versa.